# PyCharm cant choose a system interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to make a system interpreter and then linking a library that is in the same folder as my main.py file. When I try to make the system interpreter it just says "" and then when I click on it I cant choose anything, there is nothing in the list at all. On the other computer I am using I can choose python3, python3.7 and python 2. Why cant I choose these on the other computer?

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm don't have embedded Python interpreter.

If you don't have yet Python installed, please install it.

Then after a new launch of Pycharm it will highly probably see that Python installation — in the opposite case you may manually add it:

[image: Adding Python interpreter]

Click on the icon, select Add..., then

[image]